# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed ERROR

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, illegalstateexception

I'm just a beginner in java coding.

This is just a random program which is at a starting level of code.

Recently i got this error and was unable to solve it. Please help me with this.

```
Exception in thread "main" Enter the first number:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at New.main(New.java:19)
```

MY PROGRAM IS AS FOLLOWS:

```
import java.util.*;
public class New {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int hour,min,sec,o;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the time:");
        hour=s.nextInt();
        min=s.nextInt();
        sec=s.nextInt();

        date  d = new date();
        d.setdate(hour,min,sec);
        System.out.println(d.display());
        s.close();

        calc c = new calc();
        int a,b;
        System.out.print("Enter the first number:");
        a=s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number:");
        b=s.nextInt();
        c.get(a,b);
        System.out.println("Which operation do you want to perform");
        System.out.println("1.Addition\n 2.Subtraction\n 3.Multiplication\n 4.Division");
        System.out.print("Enter the Operation:");
        o=s.nextInt();
        c.compute(o);

    }

    public class date {
    int hour,min,sec;

    public void setdate(int h,int m,int s){
        hour= ((h>0 && h<24)?h:0);
        min= ((m>0 && m<60)?m:0);
        sec= ((s>0 && s<60)?s:0);
    }
    public String display(){
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,min,sec);
    }}



}
public class calc {
    int a,b,o;
    double c;
    public void get(int x,int y){
        a=x;
        b=y;
    }
    public double compute(int z){
        o=z;
    switch(o)
    {
    case 1: c=a+b;
    break;
    case 2: c=a-b;
    break;
    case 3: c=a*b;
    break;
    case 4: c=a/b;
    break;
    default: System.out.println("Invalid Operation");
    }
    return c;
    }
}
```

The date part of the program works perfectly fine. The mess is with the second part of the program.

Comment: You have closed the scanner in s.close(); thats why you cant use it

Comment: you are closing scanner and then using it remove the s.close()

Comment: the **real** answer: go and google your exception message **first**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close the scanner and then call `nextInt` on it

```
 s.close(); //remove this line

 calc c = new calc();
    int a,b;
    System.out.print("Enter the first number:");
    a=s.nextInt();
```

So remove `s.close();` and your code will work

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works fine without errors now but the operation compute() in class calc is not working. Once i enter the operation, i do not get any result.. :(

Comment: @Terminator Why you think so? You never print the result!

Comment: Oh yeah nvm i forgot, thanks a lot bro! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    ...
    d.setdate(hour,min,sec);
    System.out.println(d.display());
    s.close();
    ...
```

remove the statement

```
    s.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't close the input stream, else you will not be able to read it again.

```
 s.close();
```

Display computation output:

```
double d = c.compute(o);
System.out.print("Result:" +d);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works fine without errors but the operation compute() is not working properly. Once i enter the operation, i do not get any result.. :(

Comment: Are you getting any exception then? I think it should work. Save the computation result into some variable and print to output stream. I am editing my answer for it. Good Luck and Happy Coding!